# How to make a navigation bar which disappears (with a nice animation) when you scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I am trying to do a navigation bar which disappears when scrolling, with a nice animation. Here is what i made so far.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.PNG" type="image/gif">
        <title>Top News</title> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "fixedbc">
            <div class="bwbutton">Welcome to Top News</div>
            <header>asdasd</header>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
    /* ===================   Needs   =================== */
html, body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: white;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      border:0px;
    }

/* ===================   Buttons   =================== */

.bwbutton {
    background-color:transparent;
    border:6px solid #ffffff;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Georgia;
    font-size:45px;
    padding:13px 60px;
    text-decoration:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:30%;
    left:29%;
    transition: all .1s ease-in;
}
.bwbutton:hover {
    background-color:transparent;
    border:6px solid black;
    color:black;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
.bwbutton:active {

}

/* ===================   LAYOUT   =================== */

.fixedbc {
    min-height:100%;
    background-image: url("../bc.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
marquee{
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top:1.5%;
    color:white;
}

/* ===================   Header // Nav   =================== */

header {
  background: #f5b335;
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}
// we'll add this class using javascript
.nav-up {
  top: -40px; // same as header height. use variables in LESS/SASS
}
```

Javascript:

```
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

Comment: What is it doing and what do you expect it to do? What have you done to try and understand the problem? Do you see any errors in your console? (hit F12 on Windows, Opt+Cmd+I on Mac)

Comment: You're not closing your `setInterval` properly. You're closing it with just a `}` when it needs to be `})`. Not sure if that's the solution, but you need to fix it either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Check this fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/SaurabhSonawane/u5wjuqru/7/)

If you wanted to hide navigation bar on scroll with some animation, then make its position fixed and hide it on scroll. (Need to add Jquery for this demo)

Like,
**Sample HTML**

```
<header>Header</header>
```

**Sample CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 1000px
}

header {
    position:fixed;
    background: #111111;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height:50px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
       -moz-transition: all 0.35s;
            transition: all 0.35s;
    overflow: hidden
}

header.hide {
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

**Sample Jquery**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($("header").offset().top > 50) {
        $("header").addClass("hide");
    } 
    else {
        $("header").removeClass("hide");
    }
});
```